# Music not playing properly on touch-LibGdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I have array of coins spread in the screen.I want to add sound when I touch a coin.

```
private Music coinSound;
```

in show():

```
coinSound=assetManager.get(Assets.collectCoin);
```

calling coinSound.play() here:

```
if (MyInputProcessor.isTouchDown) {
        touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
        game.camera.unproject(touchPos);
        for (int i = 0; i < coins.length; i++) {
            Rectangle textureBounds = new Rectangle(coins[i].getX(), coins[i].getY(), coins[i].getWidth(),coins[i].getHeight());

            if (textureBounds.contains(touchPos.x, touchPos.y) && !coins[i].isBreakBool()) {
                coinSound.play();
                coins[i].setTapBool(true);
            }
        }
        MyInputProcessor.isTouchDown = false;
}
```

Now sound is playing but not for all the array elements.for touch on one coin it is playing correctly every time.What do I need to change for making it play for each coins on touch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Sound` instead of `Music`.

[Sound effects](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Sound-effects) are small audio samples, usually no longer than a few seconds, that are played back on specific game events such as a character jumping or shooting a gun.

```
AssetManager manager = new AssetManager();
manager.load("data/mysound.mp3", Sound.class);
manager.finishLoading();
```

Get sound from `AssetManager`

```
Sound sound = manager.get("data/mysound.mp3", Sound.class);
sound.play();
```

`Music` instances are heavy, you should usually not have more than one or two at most loaded.